# How do I implement scroll restoration in react-native's experimental WindowedListView

Tags: javascript, react-native, scroll

I want to implement a scroll restoration mechanism on react-native's experimental WindowedListView component

I've tried to set the underlying ScrollView scroll position by using `scrollTo` function - but the WindowedListView itself didn't scroll to the correct position. I suspect the cause is because it render rows incrementally, so it doesn't directly show the target row.

```
// WindowedListViewSource - refer to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Experimental/WindowedListView.js
componentDidMount() {
    this._scrollRef &&
      this._scrollRef.scrollToOffset &&
      this._scrollRef.scrollToOffset({offset, animated});
} // this didn't work :(
```

the expected result should render the list, and scroll to correct position/offset.

the actual result, the list is scrolled, but not to the correct position - just 10-20px from the top, but without any error messages.